# Seque order for selection lists

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am implementing the following. I have a view controller and I have buttons that open a table view controller with selection items. when I then select an item in a cell and go back to the view controller, previous values are blank (looks like it opens a new instance). The code I am using to go back is as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "playerselected" {

        let cell = sender as! UITableViewCell
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

        let itemController : GameViewController = segue.destination as! GameViewController
        let item : Player = frc.object(at: indexPath!) as! Player

        itemController.item2 = item
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, if you have segue from VC1 (`GameViewController`) to VC2 (`SomeTableViewController`) and then from VC2 to VC1, it's not the same instance of VC1.

If you don't use `UINavigationController`, you can simply "go" from VC2 back to VC1 by dismissing your VC2 using

```
dismiss(animated: true)
```

But how can you now pass data back to your previous controller? Start with this: in VC2 create closure variable which takes parameter of type `Player`. Then before you dismiss VC2, call this closure

```
class SomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var callback: ( (Player) -> Void )?

    func playerSelected(_ player: Player) {
        callback?(player)
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

}
```

But will happen after `callback` is called? Nothing, you have to assign what will happen before you present VC2. So you can override `prepare(for:sender:)` inside VC1 and assign destination's `callback` closure variable (when `callback` will be called, you need to change VC1's `item2`)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "segueToTableViewController" {

        let tableViewController = segue.destination as! SomeTableViewController

        tableViewController.callback = { player in 
            self.item2 = player
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I get the following error though, Value of type 'GameViewController' has no member 'callback'

Comment: @NickBrown This prepare for segue should he in `GameViewController`  and you should downcast destination vc to your Table View controller